# Cordova - Track when apps open and move to background

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, monitoring

I'm doing a research project looking at app usage, habitual use and addition. I'm programming an app using **HTML5**, **CSS3**, and **jQuery** and need a Cordova plugin that can identify when other apps are being used (i.e. open an app, move to the background, foreground, close an app). All this app needs to do is track how much users open apps and how long they use them.

We will recruit users to willingly participate in this study and only inform our research participants about the data we are tracking and how it's being used.

I know that the app I'm working on needs to be open and running in the background to be able to collect this data and I've already found Cordova plugins to prevent the app from going to sleep. I'm also considering battery usage as well.

There are parental monitoring apps that do this already and collect way more data that we need so I know it's possible. If anybody can point me in the right direction and help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You certainly can't do this on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11, natively, this certainly can be done. I can't speak for Cordova, but using Swift the AppDelegate provides all of the necessary lifecycle methods to make this possible.

Comment: @JamesWebster; They want to track when *other* apps are opened, move to the background, resume etc, not their own app.

Comment: Ah my apologies. That is quite a critical difference I missed; in which case I agree with you. :)